# System error - "the code cannot proceed because .dll was not found."

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I'm getting this error when I try to run my app:

[image: error]

I checked and there is no reason that I can see that it wouldn't be able to find `libnlopt-0.dll`. Here it is (note `GlassModelCalcualator` is the DLL that uses `libnlopt-0.dll`), in the `GlassModelCalcualatorDLL` folder:

[image]

and in the debug folder of `GlassModelCalcualatorDLL`:

[image]

I have a different program that has a console which uses `GlassModelCalcualator.dll` and that also has this issue. To fix that, I had to put `libnlopt-0.dll` in the Debug folder of `GlassModelCalcualator`.

I'm assuming this is not the same problem here since you can clearly see that `libnlopt-0.dll` is in `GlassModelCalcualator`'s Debug folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are clearly static-linking to the DLLs, so they need to be in a folder that is relative to where the EXE file is located, not relative to where the source code is located.  See [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx).

Comment: you can use sysinternals procmon to watch to see where windows is looking to try to load the dll

Comment: @RemyLebeau there is no exe file since I'm just working with dll's

Comment: DLLs can't run by themselves, they need to be loaded into a process that is created by running an EXE (the error message says `Gsi.exe`, and I also see `GmcConsole`)

Comment: @ConnorMote *there is no exe file* -- I clearly see `Gsi.exe` running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows will follow a hierarchical order when searching for dll's.

You could place your dll in the same directory as the exe or even in the Windows system folders (only if you're absolutely sure you want to keep this dll forever as there's no cleanup)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: "*or even in the Windows system folders*" - that is never a good idea

Comment: I agree its a bad idea but in some cases can be done (and in rare cases can be useful).

Comment: It is *never* a good idea to put non-system files in a system folder.  Put the DLLs in your own folder.  If you have multiple apps sharing the same DLLs, they can be put into a shared folder and registered with the OS so it knows where to find them.

Comment: I've seen it used in the system folder in a few applications (and we did it too) for dedicated standalone machines used for special purposes.